# BinarySearch in sort package

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, binary-search

I am looking at this function in Go `sort` package" `func SearchInts(a []int, x int) int` and curious if there is a straight forward way to identify if an element exists in the slice or not?

In Java Arrays.binarySearch(..) simply returns a negative value. I am curious if golang's api `func SearchInts(a []int, x int)` reports if x doesn't exist? not sure why `func SearchInts(a []int, x int)` doesn't return two values `(index,isPresent)`?

Comment: A more efficient way to do what you want it is to use a map, which has O(1) time complexity for looking if an element exists. You can just use `map[int]struct{}{}` i.e. a map with an empty struct for value, which as a result will use no memory for storing the values, but will provide the functionality to efficiently search if a element exist as key in the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply check:

```
i := sort.SearchInts(slice, value)
if i<len(slice) && slice[i]==value {
   // It exists
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have not used the function you mentioned, but according to the official [documentation of the package](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#SearchInts), the `SearchInts` function searches for x in a sorted slice of ints and returns the index as specified by Search.

So, based in the example provided at the docs, for something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}

    x := 2
    i := sort.SearchInts(a, x)
    fmt.Printf("found %d at index %d in %v\n", x, i, a)

    x = 5
    i = sort.SearchInts(a, x)
    fmt.Printf("%d not found, can be inserted at index %d in %v\n", x, i, a)
}
```

You would get the following output:

```
found 2 at index 1 in [1 2 3 4 6 7 8]
5 not found, can be inserted at index 4 in [1 2 3 4 6 7 8]
```

Fortunately enough, starting with the latest version of GO, which is 1.21, there is a new [slices](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master) package available, which includes the [`BinarySearch`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#BinarySearch) function, and it behaves similar to what you want from Java (by returning a `bool` type if the value was found) e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    names := []string{"Alice", "Bob", "Vera"}
    n, found := slices.BinarySearch(names, "Vera")
    fmt.Println("Vera:", n, found)
    n, found = slices.BinarySearch(names, "Bill")
    fmt.Println("Bill:", n, found)
}

Output:

Vera: 2 true
Bill: 1 false
```

Per the docs: *BinarySearch searches for target in a sorted slice and returns the position where target is found, or the position where target would appear in the sort order; it also returns a bool saying whether the target is really found in the slice. The slice must be sorted in increasing order.*

Adapting a bit to what you need, you could skip the `int` return value when evaluating the condition, and just use the `bool` value. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    names := []string{"Alice", "Bob", "Vera"}
    if _, found := slices.BinarySearch(names, "Bob"); found {
        fmt.Println("Bob:", found)
    }
}
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
Output:

Bob: true
```

Additionally, this function uses generics underline, so it won't work only for `int` types, but also for any other type.

Last but not least, there is an alternative version of the `BinarySearch` function which lets you use your own comparison function at [`BinarySearchFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#BinarySearchFunc). This might be useful for you as well in case you need some custom comparison logic.

You can check the full release notes for GO v1.21 at https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.21 in case you want to dive deeper.